# How to add `Python 3.x` interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python3, pycharm

I have just installed `PyCharm 2017.3.3` and I am trying to run a project written in python 3 but it doesn't run. I have checked the setting page it has only `Python 2.7`  interpreter. How can I upgrade the interpreter to `Python 3.x`.

[image]

I have checked the official PyCahrm

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Have you already checked [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html#jython) in the PyCharm help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First locate your interpreter on your Ubuntu system, then
Try these steps:

1. From the file menu click or select `settings`:

[image]

2. From left pane select `project name`, then on the right click on `project interpreter`

[image]

3. On the right click on the `project interpreter` drop down arrow and choose `show all` from the options there.

[image]

4. On the dialogue box that appears click on the `+` button on the right then click on `Add Local` text that will appear.

[image]

5. In the `Add local interpreter` dialogue box that appears select `System Interpreter` then click on the three dots to the right and navigate to your python location mine is `usr/bin/python3.5`. And with that you should have your project use that python version.

[image]